# Prevent FAST_PCT mview refresh

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

11g user here.

I would like to prevent an mview from ever using FAST_PCT as refresh method, I want FAST or COMPLETE only.

Is there a simple way? Like a hint of some kind? If not, have you ever successfully used a low intrusive workaround that prevents the FAST_PCT (but still allows for a FAST refresh) like an outer join to dual or the like?

Thank you!